# Extend selection based on boolean values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a signal as a dataframe, lets say:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

signal = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Signal"], data=np.random.random(100))
```

and a simple mask like:

```
mask = signal["Signal"] > 0.5
```

I now want to select the values of signal where the mask is true, but also the N values surrounding this selection. So if my mask is `[False, False, True, False, True, False, False]` and N=1, the selection should be based on a mask like `[False, True, True, True, True, True, False]`. Is there a way to do this quickly without having to iterate over the individual rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the surrounding elements using `shift`:

```
signal[(signal.Signal > 0.5) | (signal.Signal.shift() > 0.5) | (signal.Signal.shift(-1) > 0.5)]
```

Part of the output, for random data, is:

```
6   0.526264
7   0.613049
8   0.106939
9   0.917906
10  0.875563
11  0.269236
14  0.231961
15  0.757697
16  0.227037
```

---

An alternative would be to use `rolling` with `center=True`. If in a given window of size N (N=3 in this case) there's at least one item which is greater than the threshold - count the current row in.

```
THRESHOLD = 0.5 
signal[signal.Signal.rolling(3, center = True).max() > THRESHOLD]
```

N=3 means that you're looking at the current row + one row on either side. N=5 would mean current row + 2, etc.

Comment: Updated the answer a bit. Let me know if it solved your question.